# New install of 22, no sound front or back

Tags: sound, spdif

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a amd 6300.  PUV is showing my sound card but only output to a S/PDIF device.  I don't have an s/pdif jack on the computer, only places for the standard headphone jack. I don't get sound from the front or the rear jacks. How should I proceed?  My headset is new, and works on my notebook, so shouldn't be a problem from that end.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run `lsb_release -a` and [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1500013/edit) your question to include this information.

Comment: try unmute in "alsamixer"

Comment: Hi, have you installed  `linux-sound-base`  `alsa-base` `alsa-utils` packages?